# Light Path Expressions (LPE) in Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, scripting, render-layers

It seems like blender does not have a feature to render light path expressions like these in [RenderMan](https://rmanwiki.pixar.com/display/REN22/Light+Path+Expressions).

There's a [thread on devtalk about this](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/light-path-expressions-for-custom-aovs/9193) but I havent seen any further updates.

Essentially, I want to render the LPEs found in the [Stylit paper](https://dcgi.fel.cvut.cz/home/sykorad/Fiser16-SIG.pdf) (see figure 4).

Here's a screenshot of it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CPZC.jpg.

They are:

1. full global illumination render
2. direct diffuse render
3. direct specular render
4. first two diffuse bounces
5. and diffuse inter-reflections.

The first is straightforward but trying to generate the others using blender's cycle renderer is not trivial. I've managed to generate 2 and 3 (here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dSBZ.png) but I can't seem to render no. 5.

Is there a better way to go about this in blender? Or are there open source libraries that are probably more fitted for this?